# Raw data to string convert i.e. r'\nwow' to "wow"

Tags: python, regex

As I was browsing through a regular expression while learning python, I was not sure how to convert the regular expression pattern to normal string.

```
e.g. 
a='\nwow'  ==> print a ==> output: wow
b=repr(a)  ==> print b ==> output: \nwow
```

how to print wow from "b" variable not using "a" variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decode the raw string to get the interpreted result:

```
>>> i = r'\nwow'
>>> print(i)
\nwow
>>> print(i.decode('string_escape'))

wow
>>>
```

Note that you will not get just `wow`, because the string is `\nwow` hence the gap when I print it; also be careful about escaping because the string is now changed:

```
>>> q = i.decode('string_escape')
>>> len(q) == len(i)
False
>>> q
'\nwow'
>>> i
'\\nwow'
```